# Why we only have one gauge coupling constant for $\rm SU(2)$ gauge symmetry?

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, yang-mills

I know that in the case of a Yang-Mills $\rm SU(2)$ gauge symmetry, the covariant derivative is written as:

$$D^{\mu} = \partial^{\mu} + i\frac{g}{2}W^{\mu}_{a}\tau^{a}$$

With $g$ is the coupling constant, $W^{\mu}_{a}$ the gauge fields and $\tau^a$ are the Pauli matrices.

My question is whether there is any reason why g couldn't be different for each generator, something like $\frac{g_a}{2}W^{\mu}_{a}\tau^{a}$.

Comment: that a is a dummy index, already summed up and the only index which is there on the co-derivative operator is the mu index.

Comment: If you had a different coupling for each generator, then there would no longer be an $SU(2)$ gauge symmetry.

Comment: @Prahar thank you for your comment, but i still don't understand why that is the case. Because as I see it, any basis for the su(2) Lie algebra will give a valid SU(2) transformation after exponentiation.

Comment: Let's fix the normalization for the generators of the $SU(2)$ Lie algebra by requiring that $[ \tau^a , \tau^b ] = i \epsilon^{abc} \tau^c$. Once this normalization is fixed, we cannot have different coupling constants for each $a$.

Comment: But there is nothing preventing us from using another basis of the Lie algebra from the start, for example we can choose our basis vectors to also be Pauli matrices but with each of them scaled differently, evidently this will come with a different structure constant but will nevertheless equally generate the SU(2) group. It's this arbitrariness which bugs me unless there is a reason to choose a basis over another.

Answer (score 0):

Because the resulting term would not be gauge $symmetric$ anymore.

Comment: That's what i also thought but i tried to prove it to no avail, everything seemed to still hold up, if you have any reference that i could use that would be very helpful.